# How would I access a method/function from a HOC (Higher Order Component) in React without passing it as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a higher order component. I can inherit `props` into my Wrapped Component from the HOC but I also want to inherit it's methods/functions. What is the best way to do this.

I would like to use `this.myHocFunc`, not `this.props.myHocFunc`. I also don't want to map `this.myHocFunc` to `this.props.myHocFunc` inside the Wrapped Component either. all the logic needs to ideally happen inside the HOC component

Here is my HOC component:

```
import React, { Component } from "React";

export var MyEnhance = ComposedComponent => class extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    myHocFunc(text) {
        // text should be 'hello world'
        console.log(text);
    }  

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render() {
        return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
};
```

Here is my wrapped component:

```
import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import { MyEnhance } from "./enhance";

 @MyEnhance
 class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return <button onClick={this.myHocFunc('hello world')}</div>;
   }
 };

 ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems a bit roundabout. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: This is a very simple example. It's actually updating an app with a huge amount of components that all have functions inside them.  The components are wrapped in an HOC so I wanted to move the function into the HOC without having to update all the function references in the components `this.func` to `this.props.func`

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a job for inheritance, e.g.

```
class MyEnhancedComponent extends React.Component {
  myHocFunc(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
}

class MyComponent extends MyEnhancedComponent {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.myHocFunc('hello world')}</div>;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what your other requirements are for MyEnhance, but you may be overcomplicating things. Otherwise, you could also add the function explicitly.

```
export var MyEnhance = ComposedComponent => class extends Component {
  // ...

  enhance(instance) {
    instance.myHocFunc = this.myHocFunc.bind(instance);
  }

  render() {
    return this.enhance(<ComposedComponent {...this.props} />);
  }
}
```

Finally, if you really cannot use "normal" inheritance, you might take a look at the [traits](https://github.com/traitsjs/traits.js) pattern to have multiple inheritance. I also wrote a [very tiny library](https://github.com/jchook/traits.js) for this.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I tried to  add the function explicitly but i am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Comment: My mistake. I didn't add the myHocFunc. Once I added it I get a different error: `Uncaught TypeError: Can't add property myHocFunc, object is not extensible`

Comment: Is there a reason why simple inheritance will not work for your situation?